# Make a link in <a> tag open multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to make a link in html open the coupled URL 10 or more times.

I have no malicious intent, however. I only wish to prank a friend.

Comment: http://www.shinysearch.com/prank/fakegoogle.php

Comment: See my edited answer, I provided an example of JS usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML, you can open only one link with the `a` tag; have a look into JavaScript for this, and `window.open()` ([quoting from MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open;)):

> var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);

Example :

```
window.open('http://www.example.com'); //You maybe don't need to keep a 
                                      //reference of the newly opened window here
```

Call this as many time you need.

Beware though, it'll behave like a popup, and might be blocked automatically by the browser (as Chrome 33 does for instance).

### In action

You can have a link like this :

```
<a href="http://www.goodjoke.com" id="prank_link">
```

And in JS (included in your html file, in the `head` or at the end of `body`):

```
<script>
    //When the document is "loaded", execute the following code
    document.onload = function(){
        //Get the a element, identified by its ID
        var prank_link = document.querySelector('#prank_link'); 
    
        prank_link.onclick = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();            //Prevent the page to be changed
            var my_url = this.href;        //Store the url in the link
            
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){       //Call window.open() 10 times with your URL
                window.open(my_url);    
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/7pAwt/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it in HTML only? I have no idea how javascript works.

Comment: @TobyvanKempen No, you can't AFAIK. Don't be afraid of JS, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/JavaScript_Overview) to begin with it.